# strings not outputing before program is paused

Tags: c++

I have started making a text game and at the start the user takes a test which is then graded and the user is told how well they did. I want to pause the program to make it look like it has to take time to grade but it will not output the string I want and will go straight to pausing the program.

whenever I comment out the thread sleeping, the string will output but whenever I put it back into the program, I will go back to pausing before the string can output even though the string outputting is before the program pauses.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  char questionAnswer;
  int randomAnswer;
  string testAnswers, testKey;
   //create test answers
    for(int answer = 0; answer < 5; answer++){
      randomAnswer = rand()%4+1;
      switch(randomAnswer){
        case 1:
          testKey += 'A';
          break;
        case 2:
          testKey += 'B';
          break;
        case 3:
          testKey += 'C';
          break;
        case 4:
          testKey += 'D';
          break;
      }
    }
   //start test
    for(int question = 0; question < 5; question++){
      cout << "Question " << question+1 << ":\t";
      cin >> questionAnswer;
      while(toupper(questionAnswer) != 'A' && toupper(questionAnswer) != 'B' && toupper(questionAnswer) != 'C' && toupper(questionAnswer) != 'D'){
        cout << "\nInput Valid Answer:\t";
        cin >> questionAnswer;
      }
      testAnswers += toupper(questionAnswer);
      cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nGrading...";
    //pause fo dramatic effect
    this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    cout << "Student Answers:\t" << testAnswers << endl;
    cout << "Test Answers:\t" << testKey << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please see [mre]. Based on your description, I would expect to see about three lines in your example code -- one to output a string (that does nor show up), one to sleep, then probably another bit of output to show when the sleep ends. *Focus on demonstrating the issue!* If you have enough code to play your game, you have too much code for the question.

Answer (score 3):

That is because standard output is buffered. If you [flush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) the output before pausing, it should work.

```
cout << "\nGrading..." << flush;
this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a `\n` at the end of the string, it solves the problem.

```
cout << "\nGrading...\n";
```